# SonarQube MSBuild scanner ignore duplicate projects

Tags: sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Is there an option to ignore duplicate project GUIDs?  Seems like the scanner hooks itself into the build process and creates a output project whenever a build is run on a c# project.  Sometimes multiple builds are run, e.g. Silverlight, Portable libraries, RIA code gen, and these all cause the scanner to generate duplicates.  I've tried to eliminate the duplicates from the msbuild by changing csproj files and target files, but that is not easy (some projects are built 3 times), and I think it would be simpler if there was just a switch to ignore duplicates rather than exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my solution using Silverlight.  The only solution I found, though ugly, was to do a Powershell script to remove duplicate directories.  The contents seemed to be the same, a list of files to use for processing.  I would like to +1 for the ignore flag.

Comment: Sounds fine.  I took a different route and forked the repo [link]https://github.com/yowl/sonar-scanner-msbuild.git Not sure how the command line arguments work so haven't put in a pull request yet.